# jQuery Make Div accompany window vertical slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to have a small div on the right side of my screen, and I want it to accompany my vertical window slider. Is there any function in jQuery that returns the current vertical slider position?

The closest one I found was scrollTop() but that's only from a certain element.
Here is the

```
code
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6o368hrq/

Comment: Paste your code or make a simple jsfiddle, please :)

Comment: BTW, I will recomend you to use a `position: fixed` on CSS and not jQuery, in the case you want allways to "accompany" your vertical slider.

Comment: "only from a certain element" - `body` is also an element...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
  var scrolled = $(this).scrollTop();
  var bodyHeight = $('body').height();
  var topPercent = ((bodyHeight / scrolled) * 100) + 'vh';

  $('#btn').css('top', topPercent );

});
```

Check to see how far the window has scrolled, calculate what percentage of the body this is, then use `position: fixed` and `top: {scrolledPercentage}vh`.

Haven't had a chance to test, but that's how I'd approach this!

Comment: The element now changes position, but as it is, it does a major jump and basically disappears out of sight

Comment: I'd start by `console.log()`ing variables to check I get what I'm expecting and seeing what happens to `scrolled` and `topPercent` when you scroll. Do you get any console errors?